# About "comma + which"

Tags: relative-clauses

I feel when we use "comma + which", the clause right before "comma" can act as a subject or object of the clause after "which". so I made 5 sentences to make sure I understand right.

> 1. I get up late, which I feel I have to fix.

***I get up late*** is a object of "fix".

> 2. I eat a fruit every morning, which I think is really great for my health.

***I eat a fruit every morning*** is a subject of "is".

> 3. I drink a cup of coffee once I finish eating lunch, which I think makes me more productive.

***I drink a cup of coffee once I finish eating lunch*** is a subject of "makes".

> 4. My girlfriend is a vegetarian, which is what I like about her.

***My girlfriend is a vegetarian*** is a subject of "is".

> 5. My girlfriend is a vegetarian, which I like about my girlfriend.

***My girlfriend is a vegetarian*** is an object of "like".

Am I right to think this way?

Comment: Except in the narrowest technical sense, you have nailed it. (Actually, *which* is the subject/object in these cases; it is a 'variable' whose 'value' is the main clauses. But that's grammatical pettifoggery.)

Comment: @StoneyB, is that not a good answer? I suggest you make it an answer!

Comment: @Omnidisciplinarianist I am reluctant to post the single word "Yes" as an Answer.

Comment: @StoneyB, but you also have the phrase "grammatical pettifoggery". I think that's worth an answer.

Comment: @TBridges42 But as long as I leave buried in comments I can reuse it somewhere spectacular.

Answer (score 1):

In reality, yes.
In grammar-land, though, 'which' is actually the subject/object - 'which' refers to those sentences, though.